# iOS: viewWillUnload?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

For a `UIViewController`, in case its view is unloaded, I want to save (to an `NSString` ivar) the text string that a user has entered into a `UITextView` (or `UITextField`).

Where should I do this?

I'm assuming the `UITextView` will already have been reset to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`, correct?

So, I want to do something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillUnload {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:TEXT_VIEW_TAG];
    self.stringIvar = textView.text;
    [super viewWillUnload];
}
```

But what's the `viewWillUnload` method? Is it `didReceiveMemoryWarning`?

Comment: No, `viewWillUnload` is `viewWillUnload`, not another method...

Comment: @jv42, `viewWillUnload` is a method name I made up. It doesn't exist. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` (which tries to unload the view) is always called before `viewDidUnload`, ergo treat `didReceiveMemoryWarning` as if it were called `viewWillUnload`.

Comment: ok... This wasn't clear at all to me, maybe you could rephrase it a bit, or it's just because I hadn't my nose in a UIVC at the time I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. Use [`didReceiveMemoryWarning`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning).

Comment: ...What? Could you please elaborate?